# Semantic Search without using filetable in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

We have an file upload system and would like to use the new MSSQL2012 semantic search feature for sql server 2012. Is that possible without using filetables?

This is our schema:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two questions here.

**Can you use Semantic Search without using filetable?**

Yes, you can. It can be used on any table with Full-Text indexing turned on.
Here is the list of prerequisites:
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509116.aspx#reqenable).

Basically you can use it on the data, which is *loaded into the database.*

**The second question is whether your schema benefit from Semantic Search an to what extent**.

Looking at your scheema I understand, that your database hold only paths to the documents and their "descriptions". Therefore, you can enable Semantic Search on the columns in your database. It will allow to use Semantic Search on FileName and Description, but not on documents' contents.

In order to use Semantic Search on the contents of these documents you'll need to store these documnets in SQL database. FileTable structure helps this task, although you can choose another way of storing whole documnets in your database.

Comment: If there are several questions, why did you only answer one?

Comment: @Neolisk. Second question is whether this schema will benefit from semantic index and to what extent.

Comment: @Stoleg: It would help if you edited your answer so that it has two questions covered. Even if prefer not to expand on the second one, for any reason.

Comment: @Neolisk, have a look. Changed to "2 questions" and marked where each question begin.

Comment: @Stoleg: I think it's better like this - please have a look. If you don't like my edit, you can always revert it to the previous revision.

Comment: @Neolisk, Thank you, I like it your way.

Comment: Thank you! The files are stored in the database.Myfle was a binary type

Comment: @jvelez, if your file is stored in the database, then you should strongly consider taking advantage of FileTable. DB stores files less efficiently than file system, and FileTable is and attempt to fix this. Also you would benefit of Full Test and Semantic Search too.